# Best practice for isolating dependencies during unit tests

Tags: python, apache-spark, python-unittest

I have a Python module which contains utility methods for use in Databricks. The module essentially looks like this (`utils.py`):

```
from databricks.sdk.runtime import spark, dbutil

def someUsefulFunction():
  pass
```

etc.

I have a unit test module built in Python unittest which looks sort of like this (`test.py`):

```
from utils import someUsefulFunction
import unittest

class TestSomething(unittest.TestCase):
   def testSomeUsefulFunction(self):
      pass
```

etc.

My problem is that the `databricks.sdk.runtime` import is required for the code to run in Databricks, but if the code is running in unit tests it tries to attach to the spark runtime and fails (just from the import - it doesn't require that I use spark).

There are a couple of ideas I have:

1. separate the code that relies on spark from the code that doesn't into different modules, and
2. use a strategy pattern that uses Spark in Databricks and does something else in unit tests, or alternatively,
3. mock spark in unit tests.

As far as I know options 2 and 3 both retain a dependency on spark and will still fail.

My big issue is that I don't know in Python how to truly separate dependencies in the way I need to.

Comment: Oof, I would consider that a bug. Just importing a module should not require any such credentials be available. That's an error an explicit function call should raise. That said, possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/71516084/1126841?

Comment: @chepner That is a very similar question.  In fact that is why I created these libraries was to get code out of databricks for testing.  I work in a government environment so installing anything like spark locally is out of the question.